# Threaded App.net Conversation Into Tree

Tags: php, json, algorithm, tree

I want to create a JSON tree from a flat structure - in this case an App.net Thread.

I want JSON like this

```
"id": "12345",
"name": "Ringo",
    "data": 
    {
        "avatar": "",
        "text": "We All Live",
    },
    "children": [{
        "id": "34567",
        "name": "John",    
        "data": 
        {
            "avatar": "",
            "text": "In a pink submarine?",
        },
        "children": [{
            "id": "35555",
            "name": "George",    
            "data": 
            {
                "avatar": "",
                "text": "Don't be daft",
            },
            "children": []
        }]
    },{
        "id": "98765",
        "name": "Paul",    
        "data": 
        {
            "avatar": "",
            "text": "In a yellow submarine?",
        },
        "children": []
    }]
```

So, each post can have multiple children. Each child can have children.

The JSON coming back from App.net is **not** threaded.

```
{
    "id": "98765",
    "parent": "12345"
    "details": {
    ...}
},
{
    "id": "34567",
    "parent": "12345"
    "details": {
    ...}
},
```

I've used json_decode() to get the JSON response in to an array.  I can iterate through using foreach.

How do I put each post in the correct part of the multi dimensional array?

```
Parent
|_
  |-child
  |-child
  |  |-child
  |-child
```

etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use references, the oft forgotten hard link of PHP. Something like this:

I'm assuming you have a `$posts` array that you've gotten back from an App.net API call.

(untested, may not compile / run / may have errors / may be more efficient ways to do this)

```
// first throw everything into an associative array for easy access
$references = array();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $id = $post['id'];
    $post['children'] = array();
    $references[$id] = $post;
}

// now create the tree
$tree = array();
foreach ($references as &$post) {
    $id = $post['id'];
    $parentId = $post['parent'];
    // if it's a top level object, add it to the tree
    if (!$parentId) {
        $tree[] =& $references[$id];
    }
    // else add it to the parent
    else {
        $references[$parentId]['children'][] =& $post;
    }
    // avoid bad things by clearing the reference
    unset($post);
}

// encode it
print json_encode($tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sketching out an answer here:  all assuming you can hold all entries in RAM otherwise you will have to make some ordering assumptions and clear our your array when a full unit is done.

Create an array `posts` indexed by id holding structures with the details and an array of children.
Then iterate over your input array and for each element:

- create `posts[id]` if it hasn't been created yet
- fill in details for `post[id]`
- if there is a parent, lookup (creating it if needed -- no idea how the ordering is) `posts[parent_id]` and add this structure to the children there.

At the end you can iterate over all posts and those without a parent are the roots with their children properly filled in.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [class and example script](https://gist.github.com/3556745) to accomplish what I think you wanted.

It converts a flat structure into a hierarchical one, and also accounts for orphan updates (ones without parent updates available).

**Update.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * An App.net update.
 */
class Update extends ArrayObject
{
    /**
     * The update's children.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $children = array();

    /**
     * The parent update.
     *
     * @var Update
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * Adds a child to this update.
     *
     * @param Update The child update.
     */
    public function addChild(self $child)
    {
        $child->setParent($this);

        $this->children[] = $child;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the parent update.
     *
     * @param Update The parent update.
     */
    public function setParent(self $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    /**
     * Converts the update and its children to JSON.
     *
     * @param boolean $encode Automatically encode?
     *
     * @return string The JSON-encoded update.
     */
    public function toJson($encode = true)
    {
        $data = $this->getArrayCopy();

        if ($this->children) {
            $data['children'] = array();

            foreach ($this->children as $child) {
                $data['children'][] = $child->toJSON(false);
            }
        }

        if ($encode) {
            return json_encode($data);
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

**build.php**

```
<?php

require 'Update.php';

$updates = <<<UPDATES
[
    {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "Ringo",
        "data": {
            "avatar": "",
            "text": "We All Live"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "34567",
        "parent": "12345",
        "name": "John",
        "data": {
            "avatar": "",
            "text": "In a pink submarine?"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "98765",
        "parent": "12345",
        "name": "Paul",
        "data": {
            "avatar": "",
            "text": "In a yellow submarine?"
        }
    }
]

UPDATES;

$original = json_decode($updates, true);
$parents = array();
$children = array();

foreach ($original as $update) {
    if (empty($update['parent'])) {
        $parents[$update['id']] = $parent = new Update($update); 

        if (isset($children[$update['id']])) {
            foreach ($children[$update['id']] as $child) {
                $parent->addChild($child);
            }

            unset($children[$update['id']]);
        }
    } else {
        $child = new Update($update);

        if (isset($parents[$update['parent']])) {
            $parents[$update['parent']]->addChild($child);
        } else {
            if (false === isset($children[$update['parent']])) {
                $children[$update['parent']] = array();
            }

            $children[$update['parent']][] = $child;
        }
    }
}

// Anything in children at this point are orphans

echo "Parents:\n";

foreach ($parents as $parent) {
    echo $parent->toJson();
}

echo "\n\nOrphans:\n";

foreach ($children as $parent => $orphans) {
    foreach ($orphans as $orphan) {
        echo $orphan->toJson();
    }
}
```